How to create anisotropic hair shader with texture maps?
I'm trying to replicate a certain hair shader from a game like the reference image below.

Normally in anime style games the hair specular is manually drawn on but in this game the game utilizes different texture maps to create the hair specular
I'm wondering is there a way to replicate it with the textures provided?
Thank you in advances :D



(Not sure if the blue texture is used for this or not)
